# Why do I get different results for arity between proc and method?

Tags: ruby, arity

With `proc` and `method`, I get the following different results. Why is that?

```
proc {|x|}.arity                    # => 1 
proc {|x=1|}.arity                  # => 0 
def foo(x=1);end;method(:foo).arity # => -1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful of the fact that in ruby, `Method` and `Proc` are two different things.

For [`Proc#arity`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Proc.html#method-i-arity), the number returned is the number of arguments that would not be ignored by calling the proc.
For the first proc you declared, it takes exactly one argument, therefore it has an arity of 1.
For your second proc, it has only one argument that is optional, therefore it really does not expect an argument at all, so it is `0`.

For [`Method#arity`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Method.html#method-i-arity), the number returned is the number of arguments accepted by the method.
Your method actually expects a variable number of arguments, namely 0..1, therefore arity is expected to return a negative number, here `-1`, because there is 0 required argument, and the formula is -n-1 (n being the number of required arguments).

Note that the documentation for the `Proc#arity` is misleading because it mentions the same formula as for `Method#arity`, while it is not true.

The case of lambdas is also interesting, because:

```
lambda {|x=1|}.arity     # => -1
```

It behaves like a `Method`.

Comment: @JanDvorak What is confusing is that `proc` and `Proc` mean different things.

Comment: @sawa sorry; I meant "actually `lambda`s are `Proc`s. So..."

Comment: The point is that a `Proc` instance created by `proc` and a `Proc` instance created by `lambda` behave differently. And a `Method` instance created by `method` behaves similar to the latter.

Comment: Lambdas behave like methods, both in argument checking and in the behavior of `return`. Regular non-lambda `Proc`s behave like blocks, both in argument checking and in the behavior of `return`. Remember: "block" rhymes with "proc" and "lambda" is a Greek letter just like "method" is Greek word. (Yeah, pretty weak, I know :-D )